# Check alert rules in virtual machine ( using remote desktop) azure

Tags: azure, alert, azure-active-directory, remote-desktop

How can I see the alert rules in virtual machine ( using remote desktop) azure.
I have RDP credentials but not the azure login.
Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I see the alert rules in virtual machine ( using remote
>   desktop) Azure.

I think it is **not possible**, because `alert rules` work on Azure platform, used for manage Azure resources.

Azure VM is a resource of Azure platform, can't see the alter rules without Azure account.

Comment: we should use Azure account to login Azure and check the alert rules, hope that helps:)